# Excel 2007 align to columns by ID number

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to align/matchup misaligned data in excel. Currently the data looks like this:

```
customerid  customerid2 emailaddress          firstname         lastname

1           2           bobhope@.com          Chris             Anderson
2           1           chrisanderson@.com    Bob               Hope
7           8           Bryansmoth@.com       Jenn              Lacy
8           7           Jennlacy@.com         Bryan             Smoth
9                       123@.com
10          11          RonnieWilliams@.com   Andrew            Smoth
11          10          Andrewsmoth@.com      Ronnie            Williams
```

Basically I'm trying to get Column A and B's ID's to match accordingly and all data to the right to align. So it becomes:

```
1            1          bobhope@.com          Bob               Hope
2            2          chrisanderson@.com    Chris             Anderson
7            7          Bryansmoth@.com       Bryan             Smoth
8            8          Jennlacy@.com         Jenn              Lacy
9                       123@.com
10           10         RonnieWilliams@.com   Ronnie            Williams
11           11         Andrewsmoth@.com      Andrew            Smoth
```

I'd do this manually but there are 17,000 incorrect entries. From what I understand I can run a VBA in excel that will help correct this problem.

Comment: Hm, I totally don't see the point of column 2. You can just copy-paste column 1 there :s Are you looking for a way to reconcile column 3  with columns 4 and 5?

Comment: is `9` in `customerid2` missing unintentionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do not give code so soon but this seemed an interesting question. Try this simple code.

**My Assumptions**:

1. The name of the sheet which has data is called `Sheet1`
2. The data is in `Columns A:E`
3. There are no multiple occurrences of `customerid2`
4. Row 1 has headers

**Logic**:

1. Store the range `B:E` in an array
2. Clear the columns `B:E` for output
3. Loop though col A and match it with the col 1 of the array and if the match is found then populate the relevant row

**Code**:

I have commented the code. Still if you face a problem then simply post back.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim MyData As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lRow As Long

    '~~> This is your relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> get the last row which has data
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Get your Col B:E Range
        Set rng = ws.Range("B2:E" & lRow)

        '~~> Store the range in an array
        MyData = rng

        '~~> Clear Col B:E for output
        rng.ClearContents

        '~~> Loop through Col A
        For i = 2 To lRow
            '~~> Loop through Array
            For j = LBound(MyData) To UBound(MyData)
                '~~> If match found then write to relevant row
                If MyData(j, 1) = .Range("A" & i).Value Then
                    .Range("B" & i).Value = MyData(j, 1)
                    .Range("C" & i).Value = MyData(j, 2)
                    .Range("D" & i).Value = MyData(j, 3)
                    .Range("E" & i).Value = MyData(j, 4)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot (Before And After)**:

[image]

Comment: Not that I have an answer to the question otherwise, but I believe columns D and E should match the names in the e-mail column.

Comment: @JoeLaviano: That is because the names and email address have been placed incorrectly by OP in the question I guess. There is no Sure Shot way of knowing if an email belongs to a specific person. The only way I know is using `instr` but that again is not foolproof :) Also if you notice that the email addresses are incorrect ;)

Comment: Heh I didn't even see that, too early for me clearly. Still a quality answer as always! +1

Comment: @JoeLaviano: Thanks for taking the time to appreciate it :)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout Here is a screenshot so you can see the exact file I'm working with. I did use your VBA code but it threw an error which I'm guessing is because I didn't add in the extra data cells correctly. This is an exported file from PHPMYADMIN thus the reason it's just a mess. (short story) CEll A corresponds with data D-K. Cell B and C are the issue. Thank you SO much for your help! I saw no reply button so I hope I'm reply correctly

Screenshot: 

<a href="http://imgur.com/A2Cg4uy"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/A2Cg4uy.png" title="Hosted by imgur.com" /></a>

Comment: @ChristopherMcCowen: That is an altogether a different problem. I don't have any expertise in either `PHPMYADMIN` or `Zen Cart`. I would recommend asking a new question with `PHPMYADMIN` and `Zen Cart` tags :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I ran your code again and it work ALMOST perfectly! (I had to change the sheet name) A,B,C,D,E all seem to match. The only issue is that FGHJKL stay in the same place. (that's my fault for not including those cells) The computer seems to be under a heavy load when it's running, but the code seems to almost work. Could you adjust it to include cells F-k as shown in the screenshot? Also can we donate via PayPal? This will save me hours of work, I can't stress thanking you enough. Better yet, if I'm aloud to email the spread sheet, I'll happily pay for the conversion.

Comment: Got it, will send you an email shortly :)